# Sprockets::DoubleLinkError: Multiple files with the same output path cannot be linked ("application.js") in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-7

Sprockets::DoubleLinkError: Multiple files with the same output path cannot be linked ("application.js") in Rails 7.

After compiling assets:
[image]

Here is my manifest.json:
[image]

Directory structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message before and [this comment](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/issues/56#issuecomment-985985939) from DHH helped me resolve it.

> You have to rename one of the two files. They're both being generated at the same path which doesn't work. Normally if you use builds/application.js you don't also need app/assets/javascripts/application.js.

I renamed `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` to `app/assets/javascripts/application.assets.js` and the error resolves until the server restarts and the build asset is generated again.

Removing:

```js
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
```

from `manifest.js` resolved appears to actually resolve the issue. Since you don't need to load `application.js` if you are loading the builds folder.